# Session handling and count with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, session-variables

I am trying to test my website performance using JMeter. I just started with login implementation. After logging in my website displays the number of users logged in at the instant.

I am able to see different number sessionId created for threads in JMeter but the count is not getting updated.

Could anyone please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your "counter" count you may need to configure JMeter differently.

The most straightforward way is adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your Test Plan and given your test is using multiple iterations tick `Clear cookies each iteration?` box.

If users are being counted basing on something else you need to figure that out and amend your Test Plan accordingly, it might also be some HTTP Header so you will have to send different headers for each user via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)